# Join graphs tikz + pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, tikz-cd

I have two graphics that I would like to join into one but even more I would like to put them inside text, something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
...
\end{figure}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

the codes of my graphs are the following:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noshorthands]{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-stealth] (-1,0) -- (2.5,0) node[below]{$u$};;
\draw[-stealth] (0,-1) -- (0,2.5) node[left]{$v$};
\draw[blue] (-0.8,2)--(2.3,2);
\draw[blue] (-0.8,0.5)--(2.3,0.5);
\draw[red] (2,-0.8)--(2,2.3);
\draw[red] (0.5,-0.8)--(0.5,2.3);

\node at (0,2) [blue, font=\footnotesize, below left]{$1$};
\node at (0,0.5) [blue, font=\footnotesize, below left]{$1$};
\node at (2,0) [red, font=\footnotesize, below left]{$1$};
\node at (0.5,0) [red, font=\footnotesize, below left]{$1$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=10cm}
\tikzset{declare function={torusx(\u,\v,\R,\r)=cos(\u)*(\R + \r*cos(\v)); 
torusy(\u,\v,\R,\r)=(\R + \r*cos(\v))*sin(\u);
torusz(\u,\v,\R,\r)=\r*sin(\v);
vcrit1(\u,\th)=atan(tan(\th)*sin(\u));% first critical v value
vcrit2(\u,\th)=180+atan(tan(\th)*sin(\u));% second critical v value
vtest(\u,\v,\az,\el)=sin(-vcrit1(\u-\az,\el)+\v);
disc(\th,\R,\r)=((pow(\r,2)-pow(\R,2))*pow(cot(\th),2)+% 
pow(\r,2)*(2+pow(tan(\th),2)))/pow(\R,2);% discriminant
umax(\th,\R,\r)=ifthenelse(disc(\th,\R,\r)>0,asin(sqrt(abs(disc(\th,\R,\r)))),0);
}}
\pgfplotsset{visible stretch/.style={restrict expr to domain={vtest(atan2(rawy,rawx),%
ifthenelse(veclen(rawx,rawy)>\R,asin(rawz/\r),180-asin(rawz/\r)),\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/el})}{-0.05:1.1}},
hidden stretch/.style={restrict expr to 
domain={vtest(atan2(rawy,rawx),%
ifthenelse(veclen(rawx,rawy)>\R,asin(rawz/\r),180-asin(rawz/\r)),\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/el})}{-1.1:0.05}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1}
\pgfplotsset{view={35}{60},axis lines=none}
\begin{axis}[]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,10,...,350}  
    {\addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:361,smooth,samples=71,ultra thin,gray!30]  
        ({torusx(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)});
     \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,ultra thin,gray!30]  
        ({torusx(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(#1,x,\R,\r)});
    }
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,10,...,350}  
    {\addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:361,smooth,samples=71,visible stretch,very
    thin,gray!50]  
        ({torusx(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)});
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,visible stretch,very
    thin,gray!50]  
        ({torusx(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(#1,x,\R,\r)});}
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,opacity=0.6,
        red,very thick,dashed]  
        ({torusx(-90,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(-90,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(-90,x,\R,\r)}); 
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,visible
    stretch,red,very thick]  
        ({torusx(-90,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(-90,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(-90,x,\R,\r)}); 
        
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,opacity=0.6,
        red,very thick,dashed]  
        ({torusx(0,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(0,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(0,x,\R,\r)}); 
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,visible
    stretch,red,very thick]  
        ({torusx(0,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(0,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(0,x,\R,\r)}); 
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,opacity=0.6,
        blue,very thick,dashed]  
        ({torusx(x,0,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,0,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,0,\R,\r)}); 
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,visible
    stretch,blue,very thick]  
        ({torusx(x,0,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,0,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,0,\R,\r)});
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,opacity=0.6,
        blue,very thick,dashed]  
        ({torusx(x,80,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,80,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,80,\R,\r)}); 
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,visible
    stretch,blue,very thick]  
        ({torusx(x,80,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,80,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,80,\R,\r)});
\end{axis};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like the result to be something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure if I understand correctly your question... if you want the two diagram together, just put them together. You can use the `baseline` option for vertical alignment, or you can look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236233/how-to-align-text-and-picture-horizontally-and-vertically).

I saved your torus graph (which is quite heavy to compute) in a file called `torus.pdf`. Then you just put the two graphics on the same line:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=10cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noshorthands]{babel}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-1cm]
        \draw[-stealth] (-1,0) -- (2.5,0) node[below]{$u$};;
        \draw[-stealth] (0,-1) -- (0,2.5) node[left]{$v$};
        \draw[blue] (-0.8,2)--(2.3,2);
        \draw[blue] (-0.8,0.5)--(2.3,0.5);
        \draw[red] (2,-0.8)--(2,2.3);
        \draw[red] (0.5,-0.8)--(0.5,2.3);

        \node at (0,2) [blue, font=\footnotesize, below left]{$1$};
        \node at (0,0.5) [blue, font=\footnotesize, below left]{$1$};
        \node at (2,0) [red, font=\footnotesize, below left]{$1$};
        \node at (0.5,0) [red, font=\footnotesize, below left]{$1$};

        % Add the arrow!
        \draw[thick, ->] (3, 1.5) to[bend left] ++(2,0);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{torus.pdf}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

But notice that if you want the diagram always in that position, you **should not use `figure`** --- [that environment is for *floating* figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat). Just use a `center` environment in that case, otherwise, if there is no space for the figure it will move around.

Comment: Saving it in pdf does not increase the size of my document? Is it possible to compile the file without the need to save the torus in pdf?

Comment: I do not think --- the code generated is PDF anyways, so I expect very small differences. But you can try --- you just put your `tikz` code instead of the `includegraphics`. Just be sure to *not* add a blank line (which will put the images one on top of the other,  because there will be a paragraph).

Comment: Checked: the file with the `includegraphics` is 236443 bytes. Without, with the `tikzpicture` embedded, is 236209 bytes. Virtually the same.  The difference is that the compilation with the `includegraphics` is less than 3 seconds, and 1 minute 10 seconds with the plain TikZ included.

Comment: You are very right, thank you very much. If I wanted my chart to not take up so much space, do you have any advice?

Comment: This is another question --- better post it, you have the MWE ready ;-). But you have 2 roads: reduce the resolution (less points per circle, for example) or create a raster image (for example, a 200dpi jpg will be around 30kbyte) and include it with `includegraphics`.  (see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605006/convert-pdf-to-image-with-high-resolution)